# It was not possible to locate part of the path XML

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, xml, web

Im facing a bug in my website, When I try to load to a Xmldocument xml from my solution It crashes.

Im putting the correct path to the file and still it says its not. I tried using server.mapPath and tried to do it in hand and still nothing.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(@"C:\Users\vardi\OneDrive\Project\NitaiVardiProject\myTeam.xml");
```

Comment: Is the ASP.NET app running on the same machine you're trying to access the site from? Or is the app on a separate server machine?

Comment: Try `Server.MapPath("~/myTeam.xml)`. a tilde (~) - this represents the root of the website

Comment: https://mariusschulz.com/blog/getting-the-web-root-path-and-the-content-root-path-in-asp-net-core

Comment: Can you open file using File Explorer?